# asp core ef migrations on production server

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Can't perform migrations on production server.
Command "dotnet ef database update" works on my computer but fails on production
Steps i tried are:
1. Fill in checkbox `execute code first migrations` in Visual Studio before publish.
2. `dotnet ef database update` not working . I installed .NET SDK but it doesn't have libraries needed.

Any suggestions appeciated.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There are a couple options:

1. Generate a SQL script using `dotnet ef migrations script` and run it on your production database.
2. Call `dbContext.Database.Migrate()` at runtime during application startup (but be careful when running multiple apps/database clients)

Also, in the next release (1.0.0-preview3) of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`, we'll be shipping `ef.exe` which you can point directly to assemblies (instead of `project.json` files) to perform migrations.

Comment: both works! thank you + hint about ef.exe. Waiting for preview3 :)

Comment: where I should put the script generated by migrations on production server ?

Comment: @bricelam Does `migrations script` generate the script for all changes since the initial migration? After I have run the script on the production database, how do I apply newer migrations in future? How do I keep track of what has been updated on the production server?

Comment: Add `--idempotent` to get a script that only applies unapplied migrations. Or you can specify *to* and *from* arguments to get a script for a range of migrations

Comment: time that this answer should be updated @bricelam . We have dotnet 5.0

Comment: Does this script create a differences script i e I

Answer (score 11):

You can generate a migration script by running the following command:

```
Script-Migration -From older_migration_name -To newer_migration_name -Context ApplicationDbContext
```

The script will have a random name and will reside in the following path:

```
<Your_Project_Drive>:\<Your_Project_Folder>\<Your_Project_Folder.Model>\obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\<Some_Random_Name>.sql
```

Now just run that script on the targeted DB of production server.

Comment: What if their on different same server different creditnisls I use shared hosting

Answer (score 2):

It is highly recommended you check which changes EF Core is going to perform using the `dotnet ef migrations scripts` command, as suggested by others.

However, once you are ready to perform your database migration, make sure your `appsettings.Production.json` file contains the necessary information to connect to your production database, and then run:

```
dotnet ef database update --context MyContext -- --environment Production
```

The `--` token directs `dotnet ef` to treat everything that follows as an argument and not try to parse them as options. Any extra arguments not used by `dotnet ef` are forwarded to the app. ([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#aspnet-core-environment))

Answer (score 0):

To avoid making a sql script and just applying my migrations directly to an azure SQL server with connection string in my appsettings.Production.json file, I did so with the following and it worked:

`dotnet ef database update --project example-api.domain --startup-project example-api.api --context ExampleContext -- --environment Production`

As a note, my dbContext.cs class resided inside of the example-api.domain project.